# All div inside row should be same height of the firstchild of row

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var tg = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0];
for (var c = 0; c < ts.length; i++) var ch = document.getElementsByClassName('o,s,t');
for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
  var mh = t g[c].firstChild.clientHeight;
  ch[i].style.height = m h + "px";
  if (tg[c].parentNode.tagName === "BODY") {
    ch[i].style.height = "auto";
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = t g;
  }
}
}
```

```css
.o {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}
.o,
.s,
.t {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="o">vzxvxzv</div>
  <div class="s">sdfs</div class="t">sdf
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="o"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to change all div inside `row` be similar to the height of `firstchild` of row also if the `classes` are outside of row the `div` height will be auto .what's the problem in my code can anyone explain also I dont want to change it from css.

the class `s` and `t` should be same height to `o`.

Comment: Why oyu don't check the console? `{
  "message": "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 35,
  "colno": 13
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick :

```
var row = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0];
var insideRow = row.childNodes;
for(var i = 1; i < insideRow.length; i++) {
  insideRow[i].style.height = insideRow[0].style.height; // set height of element 1..n of DIV 'row' to height of element 0 of DIV 'row'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` won't work this way. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.o,.s,.t')` insteaad.